# Adjust font size in Navigation Title

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to make the font of the title of the navigation bar adjusted with the width?

Same behaviour as a `[UILabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES]`.

I'm trying setting the appearance of the NavigationBar, but no success so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing something like:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

where `titleLabel` is a custom `UILabel` that you've initialized and customized.

Check out this [Fontful code](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/Fontful/blob/master/Fontful/ACFFontViewController.m#L20-L29), for example.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with the standard title item. You can still add your custom `UILabel` to the navigation bar and take care of the title changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the font of title.

Instead try out this..

```
self.title = @"My title is this.";
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [self.title sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0]].width, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    label.text = self.title;
    [label release];
```